# Single Table Messaging System in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently working on a messaging system for one of my project. I am using single table to store **messages** and **replies**(i.e with parent_id).

Here is the table structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
          `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NULL,
          `sender_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
          `receiver_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
          `who` enum('bride','member') NOT NULL,
          `subject` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
          `body` text NOT NULL,
          `sent_date` datetime NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

Where **parent_id** is the id of the message to which we replied. if **parent_id=NULL** then its a new message

Where who is the **who** sent that message- i.e **bride** or **members**. I have two separate tables for bride & member details.

Now I want a query to list messages in INBOX(just like GMAIL- bunch of conversations[messages+replies to that]).

Can you please help me to build the query?

This is what I was working on :

```
SELECT id
     , parent_id
     , sender_id
     , receiver_id
     , who
     , subject
     , body
     , sent_date 
  FROM `messages` 
 WHERE sent_date IN ( SELECT MAX( sent_date ) FROM `messages` WHERE receiver_id = 1 GROUP BY sender_id ) 
   AND who = 'bride' 
   AND receiver_id = 1 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 8
```

Comment: " if parent_id=NULL then its a new message" - so how come parent_id 'not null'?

Comment: Shame, the NULL idea was better!

Comment: what are the things you actually want to display ?

Comment: Message From, subject & body, date

Comment: There's no recursion in vanilla mysql, so choices include: building a sproc; joining the table to itself as often as could be required (yuk); switching to a nested set model (or similar); or handling the recursion at the application level (e.g. with a bit of php). Most of these options are, I suspect, discussed widely elsewhere which is why (I'm guessing) your question has received so many down votes.

Comment: We *can help you* build the query and will gladly do. But we won't *write it for you*. Please try something first.

Comment: Thanks Yak, I have added query in the question please check. thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Strawberry, I made some necessary changes. Hope its fine. I am expecting solution from you. please help.

Comment: So you simply want message threads (with replies) ordered by most recent reply, right? So, to clarify, can replies have replies?

Comment: yes replies can have replies, but I need latest replies in inbox.. on click of that all old messages relate to that reply will list.. just like Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all top-level messages (ie. not a reply) sent to a person identified with ID `1`, as well as all direct replies to these messages (1 level deep, no recursion):

```
SELECT
    messages.*,
    replies.*
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN messages AS replies ON (replies.parent_id = messages.id)
WHERE messages.receiver_id = 1
ORDER BY id messages.sent_date, replies.sent_date
```

Now, from your sample code, it looks like you only want the latest message (and their replies), then:

```
SELECT
    lastMessage.*,
    replies.*
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY sent_date
    WHERE messages.receiver_id = 1
    LIMIT 1 
) AS lastMessage
LEFT JOIN messages AS replies ON (replies.parent_id = lastMessage.id)
ORDER BY id replies.sent_date
```

I do not understand the condition `who = 'bride'` though.